# How can i pass a dynamic url to another url

Tags: python, django

Im new to Django.
So, my problem is that i want my dynamic url like this:

```
website.com/password/2332
```

"2332" is the dynamic part

to pass to this:

```
website.com/password/2332/revealpassword
```

urls.py:

```
path("password/<str:link>", views.password),
path("password/<str:link>/revealpassword", views.reveal_password, name="reveal_password")
```

html file:

```
<a href="{% url 'password:reveal_password' link %}">Reveal</a>
```

the Problem is at the "link". How can i pass the stuff that is in the url to the new url

Comment: Your view should pass it to the context when you render the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should pass it to the context when you render the template. So your `password` view looks like:

```
def password(request, link):
    # …
    context = {
        # …,
        'link': link
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

this thus will "inject" the `link` when you render the template, such that you can use the `link` in the `{% url … %}`.